# In Android how to implement broadcast receiver through kivy for bluetooth

Tags: python, kivy

I want to automate Bluetooth Pairing functionality for Android. How we can implement Broadcast receiver using kivy and python for Android.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call the android bluetooth api using pyjnius. There's a brief bluetooth example [here](https://gist.github.com/tito/7432757).